# Which encoding should i use when converting NSURLRequest.HTTPBody (form POST data) into NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, uiwebview

i'm using UIWebView to intercept POST requests (Forms).
i'm using the method "shouldStartLoadWithRequest" of the UIWebView:

```
NSData* data = request.HTTPBody;
NSString* bdy = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (bdy)
{
   NSString* decoded = [bdy stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

this can be a POST request from anywhere (actually those are POSTS from SAML IDPS whoever is familliar with it).

i've seen some posts that are using "Ascii" encoding, and some that use "UTF8" encoding.
what's the correct encoding i should use? can i somehow get it from the request and use that?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use whatever encoding was used by the HTML page you are loading.

Comment: @rmaddy - the post is done via SAML identity provider, i don't know what's the encoding of the HTML that is loaded... (as i'm catching the request before the HTML is loaded)